# Click not fired for child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/tsxb8/

```
$('.parent').on('click', function() {
   alert(1); 
});
$('.child').on('click', function() {
   alert(2); 
});
```

I need to launch some code, which is attached to a child element, when a parent element is clicked.

As I can see, childs click handler isn't fired when user clicks on a parents area (darker grey, alert = 1), which isn't a part of a childs area (lighter grey, alert = 2).

How do I fix this?

Comment: if you click on the child do you want the parent event to fire

Comment: Actually, user may click directly on a child element. I want some consistent way to handle clicks on both elements and make my code to work only once.

Comment: "both clicks are fired. I only want callback from both"? Huh?

Comment: then register both the handlers to the parent element... why register the handler to child element

Comment: I've edited the question, click on a child element should trigger one callback.

Comment: `event.stopPropagation()` or `return false` after alert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trigger the click on the child explicitly in the parent handler:

```
$('.parent').click(function() {
    alert(1);
    $(this).find('.child').click();
});

$('.child').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // Prevent bubbling to parent, to avoid loop
    alert(2);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/tsxb8/1/)